# Can you use masks to mask out your Hdri background?

Tags: rendering, masking, hdri

I'm currently rendering a small animation which uses a HDRI as it's background and I was wondering if there is a way to mask out parts of the HDRI using an object layer in my project so I can export a (masked) transparant HDRI

Comment: It's better and more flexible to use render passes. Environment pass is the one you're interested in, make sure Transparent in render settings is enabled and you render to format accepting alpha channel (preferably openEXR). Then you will have 2 passes from start - scene with transparent background and environment layers

Comment: I am currently using this but in the final outputs I don't have my environment layer masked out, its just the full hdri. I want to be able to use the environment layer with transparency..